# Difference between observeAsState and collectAsState and when to use each in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, state-management

I am learning Jetpack Compose but facing some issues in understanding states. Can someone explain these two? observeAsState and collectAsState. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `observeAsState` is an extension on `LiveData`.
   Starts observing this `LiveData` and represents its values via `State`.
   Uses `Lifecyle` internally for safely observing the data.
2. `collectAsState` is an extension on `StateFlow`.
   Collects values from this `StateFlow` and represents its latest value via State.
   You need to handle the collection as per appropriate `Lifecyle`.

Source: [Compose#LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/livedata/package-summary) & [Compose#Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsState(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)).

Comment: And now `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` exists, to internally use `Lifecycle` for safely collecting the data.

Comment: @Blundell what about `LiveData`?

Comment: There's isn't one available, you would have to do it yourself: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose read the "Note: You are not limited to these integrations."

Answer (score 0):

An addition of Darshan´s answer is that in version `2.6.0-alpha.1`, we have a new extension function that takes care of lifecycle when collecting `StateFlow`.

Link of release notes: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.6.0-alpha01)

Example: [Medium Article](https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/how-to-safely-collect-flows-lifecycle-aware-in-jetpack-compose-a-new-approach-ed20ead25be9)